# Битрикс. Не работает календарь отсутствий сотрудников

Tags: битрикс, календарь

Выгружаю Пользователей из 1С. Но в календаре отсутствий не появляется зеленая полоса с типом отпуска "Ежегодный". Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Также есть тестовый сервер. Когда делаю выгрузку туда - всё нормально в календаре отсутствий отображается. Для обмена использую компонент bitrix:intranet.users.import.1c

Для календаря отсутствий использую компонент bitrix: intranet.absence.calendar
Пример XML файла и скриншоты прикладываю.

Можно например в XML-файле найти запись с ИД 6361495b-b9f5-11dc-8fe4-001a4bba020a_ff8c1e64-2b8e-11e9-a2de-40a8f02e4f3e_OEG  (строка 69426)
У этой записи есть узел <ПричинаОтсутствия>В ежегодном отпуске - но в календаре отсутствий  такой тип отсутствия почему то не отображается. помогите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скрины:
https://my-files.ru/adgiqf
https://my-files.ru/am34ih
https://my-files.ru/ngqww9
https://my-files.ru/e4vpql
https://my-files.ru/s8s2tj
https://my-files.ru/qm5fan
https://my-files.ru/8eau8z
https://my-files.ru/rro41q

Comment: XML: https://my-files.ru/pa14xm